# How to create a list of coordinates from centre coordinate in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list with a pair of coordinates:
e.g. coord_list = [[1,2]]
For this coordinate, I would like to append to the list coordinates that are +/- 2 points away from both the x and y coordinates. The list will contain 25 pairs of coordinates in the end, with the centre coordinate as the first element.

Any suggestions about how to go about this in Python? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: only tried brute force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Solution

We can construct from the `x` and `y` coordinate of the point
the range of numbers of the points which are surrounding the point
by up to `k = 2`.

Then we build all possible combinations of these possible `x` and `y` coordinate values.
This can be neatly done with list expressions by combining two for-clauses.
Due to your desire that the original point should be placed at the beginning, we add an `if [x, y] != point` clause to exclude the
original point from listing by the list-expression but we add it at the beginning extra to this list-comprehension `[point] + [ <list-comprehension>]`.

The nice thing of this solution is that you can vary `k`, e.g. `k=3` or just one layer of cells around the original cell by setting `k=1`.

```
def vary_around(val, k=2):
    return list(range(val - k, val + k + 1))

def points_around(point, k=2):
    x, y = point
    xs = vary_around(x, k=k)
    ys = vary_around(y, k=k)
    return [point] + [[x, y] for x in xs for y in ys if [x, y] != point]
```

#### Test It

You can try it:

```
In [39]: points_around([1, 2], k=2)
Out[39]: 
[[1, 2],
 [-1, 0],
 [-1, 1],
 [-1, 2],
 [-1, 3],
 [-1, 4],
 [0, 0],
 [0, 1],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 3],
 [0, 4],
 [1, 0],
 [1, 1],
 [1, 3],
 [1, 4],
 [2, 0],
 [2, 1],
 [2, 2],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 4],
 [3, 0],
 [3, 1],def points_around(point, k=2):
    x, y = point
    xs = vary_around(x, k=k)
    ys = vary_around(y, k=k)
    return {tuple(point): [[x, y] for x in xs for y in ys if [x, y] != point]}

# now, you get:
reduce(lambda dct, dct1: dct.update(dct1) and dct, [points_around(point, k=2) for point in coord_list])


 [3, 2],
 [3, 3],
 [3, 4]]

In [40]: len(points_around([1, 2], k=2))
Out[40]: 25
```

With:

```
coord_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

You apply this function again using list-comprehensions:

```
point_groups = [points_around(point, k=2) for point in coord_list]
```

#### Further Suggestion

Probably you want the original point at the beginning to
have it distinguished from the rest of the points.

How about using a dictionary for this purpose?

```
def merge_dicts(dct, dct1):
    dct.update(dct1)
    return dct

def points_around(point, k=2):
    x, y = point
    xs = vary_around(x, k=k)
    ys = vary_around(y, k=k)
    return {tuple(point): tuple([(x, y) for x in xs for y in ys if [x, y] != point])} # key must be a tuple and not a list
# in a dictionary so probably better to make everything a tuple

from functools import reduce

defun coords_to_points_dict(coord_list, k=2):
    return reduce(merge_dicts, [points_around(point, k=k) for point in coord_list])

point2surrounding_points = coords_to_points_dict(coord_list, k=2)
```

```
point2surrounding_points
# it outputs:

{(1, 2): ((-1, 0),
  (-1, 1),
  (-1, 2),
  (-1, 3),
  (-1, 4),
  (0, 0),
  (0, 1),
  (0, 2),
  (0, 3),
  (0, 4),
  (1, 0),
  (1, 1),
  (1, 3),
  (1, 4),
  (2, 0),
  (2, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (2, 3),
  (2, 4),
  (3, 0),
  (3, 1),
  (3, 2),
  (3, 3),
  (3, 4)),
 (3, 4): ((1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (1, 4),
  (1, 5),
  (1, 6),
  (2, 2),
  (2, 3),
  (2, 4),
  (2, 5),
  (2, 6),
  (3, 2),
  (3, 3),
  (3, 5),
  (3, 6),
  (4, 2),
  (4, 3),
  (4, 4),
  (4, 5),
  (4, 6),
  (5, 2),
  (5, 3),
  (5, 4),
  (5, 5),
  (5, 6))}
```

This dictionary you can query with your points to get their surrounding points.

Comment: @DanielHao the OP didn' mention any boundaries. And why the coordinate system shoudl not have negative values?

Comment: What's `(-2,-2)` mean then?  It's probably fine - since it's not asked.

Comment: @DanielHao `(-2, -2)` just means: in the quadrant to the left bottom relative to the point `(0, 0)` - by going 2 to the left and 2 downwards relative to `(0, 0)`. The origin `(0, 0)` might be quite arbitrarily set.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to generate the 24 additional coordinates and append them to the original list:

```
coords  = [[1,2]]
coords += [ [x+d//5-2,y+d%5-2] for x,y in coords
            for d in range(25) if d != 12 ]

print(coords)
[[1, 2],  [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [-1, 2], [-1, 3], 
 [-1, 4], [0, 0],  [0, 1],  [0, 2],  [0, 3], 
 [0, 4],  [1, 0],  [1, 1],  [1, 3],  [1, 4], 
 [2, 0],  [2, 1],  [2, 2],  [2, 3],  [2, 4], 
 [3, 0],  [3, 1],  [3, 2],  [3, 3],  [3, 4]]
```

You could generalize it into a function for any distance like this:

```
def addNeighbors(coords,distance=2):
    coords += [ [x+dx,y+dy] for x,y in coords
                for dx in range(-distance,distance+1)
                for dy in range(-distance,distance+1)
                if dx or dy ]
```

Comment: The function is designed to add the the existing list assuming it starts with the center coordinate.  So no, there is no need to return coord because it is updated by the process.

Comment: The input is supposed to be [[1,2]] as per the OP